# Replace first character with same character plus something else?

Tags: regex, vim, vi

If you have a range of lines (not the entire file) that start with some variable number of spaces followed by some alphabetic characters:

```
   aaaa
   bbbb
   cccc
   DDDD
```

which you'd like to convert to this:

```
   # aaaa
   # bbbb
   # cccc
   # DDDD
```

how would you do that in Vi?

I was thinking something along the lines of:

s/[a-z,A-Z]/# (something)/

but I'm not sure how to express (something) as whatever was found that matched.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
:g/^ *[a-zA-Z]/s/^/# /
```

- `g` for lines matching
- `/^ *[a-zA-Z]/` spaces+alpha
- `s/^/# /` replace start of the line with `#`

To directly answer your question, `(something)` should be `&`. Obviously your expression would match the first alpha character wherever it appears, in the line, and insert the `#` there.

Comment: Interesting!  It's almost like you've merged two regex expressions into one.  But what if you want to do it over a range of lines m,n instead of globally?  I tried it substituting m,n for g and it comments out more than the given range.

Comment: @Robert Don't remove the `g`. `:3,7g/^ *[a-zA-Z]/s/^/# /`.

Answer (score 1):

to fix your sed command (you can replace `\w` to [a-zA-Z] for your environment)

```
sed 's/\(^ \w*\)/#\1/' file
```

#### Explanation

- `\1` represents the previous match in `( )`, if there are several pair of `( )`, use the sequence number `\2`, `\3`

If you need do it in vi/vim, run this:

```
:%s/\(^ \w*\)/#\1/g
```

Comment: I've re-worded the question to make it clear that these strings don't start at the beginning of the line.  Also that I'm operating on a range of lines, not the entire file.  Thanks for your response but I'll figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

To add one more option into the mix: `:%s/^\s\+/&# /`

The `/^\s\+` matches one or more spaces at the beginning of the line, the `&` is replaced with the string that was matched, and then the `#` is added on to the replacement.